# group tikz shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % RED                                                                                                                                       
  \draw (0.0, 0.0) -- (0.0, 2.0) -- (1.0, 3.0);
  \node at(0,0){black};
  % BLACK                                                                                                                                     
  \draw[color=red] ($(0.0, 0.0) + (1.5, 0.0)$) -- ($(0.0, 2.0) + (1.5, 0.0)$) -- ($(1.0, 3.0) + (1.5, 0.0)$);
  \node[color=red] at ($(0,0) + (1.5, 0.0)$){red};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am shifting all elements in red by (1.5, 0.0). What if I had some highly complex or multiple repetitive drawings!

Is it possible to group all elements in black in an object called Black and elements in red in an object Red and then simply place Red at Black.east with anchor west?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose  shape (or whatsever) into `scope` and shift `scope` for desired amount:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % RED
\draw (0,0) node[below] {black} -- (0,2) -- (1,3);
  % BLACK
    \begin{scope}[xshift=15mm]
\draw[red] (0,0) node[below] {red} -- (0,2) -- (1,3);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it not possible to anchor a `scope` to another `scope`? If Black became wider for some reason it would start to overlap Red. Or I could be interested to find the exact centre of Black.

Comment: so far (as i know) it is not possible to shift `scope` relatively to another scope.

Comment: @Zarko I believe (cannot test now, so please correct me if I'm wrong) that this is possible with the `local bounding box=<name>` option that can be passed to a scope. This can then be referenced with `<name>.<anchor>`, allowing to use `shift={(<name>.<anchor>)}` in a second scope.

Comment: @Max, thic can be a way. i will test this at late evening (other work had to do now :-) )

Comment: @ZarkoI don't know when it is late in the evening for you, where I am now it's already 20.20 (or 8.20 PM, whatever you prefer :) ), but thank you anyway!

Comment: @Max, your suggestion really has effect!

Comment: @Viesturs Great! Maybe Zarko could add this to his answer, for future reference.

Comment: unfortunately all my test of combination of the `scope` with `local bounding box` doesn't provide usable result. you need to define offset of the next shape staring coordinate (and than not use `scope`.

Answer (score 1):

Another options to control the position only from a point is using relative coordinates

```
\draw[style_options] (initial_x,initial_y) -- ++(x_shifting,y_shifting) ...;
```

To create it like a objet you can use code definitions

```
\def\my_objet_name#arg1#arg2... {definition_objet_tikz_instrutions}
```

The definition allows to anidate the drawing instruction in others like foreach statement, changing the initial coordinate and changing the color, insert the counter variable in the text; in a scope environmet you can also shift, rotate, and scale the objet, using transform shape to force the nodes to rotate and scale.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % BLACK                                                                                                                                       
    \draw
    (0,0)%Initial point
        node[anchor=north]{black}
        -- ++(0,2)%Relative point 1 shifted xshift=0, yshift=2 the coordinate is  (0,2)
        -- ++(1,1)%Relative point 2 shifted xshift=1, yshift=1 from point 1 (0,2 )the coordinate is  (1,3)
    ;
    \draw[red]
    (1.5,0)%Initial point
        node[anchor=north]{red}
        -- ++(0,2)%Relative point 1 shifted xshift=0, yshift=2 the coordinate is  (1.5,2)
        -- ++(1,1)%Relative point 2 shifted xshift=1, yshift=1 from point 1 (0,2 )the coordinate is  (2.5,3)
    ;

    \def\myobjet(#1)#2{% 1:Initial coordinate, #2:Styles
        \draw[#2]
        (#1)%Initial point
            node[anchor=north]{#2}
            -- ++(0,2)
            -- ++(1,1)
        ;
    }
    %drawing the objet
    \myobjet(3,0){blue}
    %The objet anidate in other drawing automated instructions
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xn using {\x*20}]in {0,...,5}{
        \myobjet(4.5+\x,0-\x*0.5){blue!\xn!red}%Shifted and color change
    }
    %Second objet anidating the first in a scope environmet for another transformations
    \def\myobjetB(#1)#2[#3][#4]{% 1:Shifting using scope  2: color 3: rotation  4:scale
        \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}, rotate=#3,scale=#4, transform shape]
            \myobjet(0,0){#2}
        \end{scope}
    }
    %The second objet anidate in other automated drawing instruction
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xn using {\x*20}]in {0,...,5}{
        \myobjetB(0+\x*1.5,-3-\x*0.3){blue!\xn!green}[-\xn][0.3+0.2*\x]%Shifted, color changed, rotated, scaled...
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```